# Javascript: How to output multiple arrays with a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Please help. I'm just new at this. I've been trying to output 2 set of arrays with a loop and I couldn't seem to figure out.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
cars=["BMW","Volvo","Saab","Ford"];
type=["Sports","Luxury","Premium","Economy"];
var i=0;
var a=0;
while (cars[i])
{
document.write(cars[i] + " - " + type[a]"<br/>");
i++;
}
</script>
```

What I want to be the result is:

```
BMW - Sports
Volvo - Luxury
Saab - Premium
Ford - Economy
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Be careful to not use any form of `document.write` in a real application in a script block unless you're putting it inside a document ready handler like (using jQuery) `$(function() { ... })`. Writing from inside a script block directly will have performance penalties for most browsers as they have to stop rendering and recalculate all the html on the page.

Comment: Also, in this case a `for` loop makes far more sense than a `while loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the type[a] to type[i]. Since the arrays seem to be parallel, you can use the same index.

```
while (cars[i])
{
document.write(cars[i] + " - " + type[i] + "<br/>");
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As the entries you want to print out are at the same indexes in the arrays, just use `i` in both (and add he missing `+` after `type[i]`):

```
document.write(cars[i] + " - " + type[i] + "<br/>");
// Here ------------------------------^  ^-- this was the missing +
```

Comment: While it doesn't apply to this specific array situation, nested for loops would be a good thing to read up on.